# Cannot modify the array passed as parameter

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have this function that has to read from a csv. It does but when i try to print the value in the main after `read_csv` without returning a `void**`, throw segv. Instead, if i return the array and print the value as it is now the main, it works correctly. So, Why aren't changes made inside functions persisted in main?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define NITEMS 7
#define SIZE sizeof(Data)
#define K 5 
    
typedef struct _data
{
    int id;
    char field1[50];
    int field2;
    float field3;
}Data;
    
void ** read_csv(void **array, const char *filename){
    int capacity = 1, size = 0; 
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("errore");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    Data *row;
    while (!feof(file)){ 
        row = malloc(sizeof(Data)); 
        if (row == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to allocate new row!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        fscanf(file,"%d,%49[^,],%d,%f\n",&row->id,&row->field1,&row->field2,&row->field3);
    
        if (size >= capacity) {
            capacity = 2 * capacity; 
            array = (void **)realloc(array, capacity * sizeof(void**));
        }
        array[size] = row;
        size++;
        printf("\n\n%d", ((Data*)array[0])->id);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return array;
}
    
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3){
        printf("\n Please make sure that each file is inserted in correct way: \n  ./main first(csv)  second (ordered csv) third(k) fourth(field)\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    void ** array = malloc(sizeof(void **));
    if(array == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    // read_csv(array,argv[1]) --> this don't mantain the changes
    array = read_csv(array, argv[1]);  // this yes
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: `void ** array = malloc(sizeof(void **));` it should be `sizeof(void *)`. The `sizeof` argument always has one less `*` than the pointer you're assigning to.